# Macro with new arguments

Tags: c, macros

I wrote this macro for searching number in array:

```
#define FIND(VALUE,ARR,INDEX){\
    int i;\
    INDEX = -1;\
    for(i = 0;i <sizeof(ARR)/sizeof(VALUE); i++){\
        if(ARR[i] == VALUE){\
            INDEX = i;\
        }\
    }\
\
}
```

My questions is, will it be a problem if I define `int i` in the macro and also in the main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `i` in the macro will hide any other `i` declared either in the surrounding context or globally. Whether one regards this as a problem or not depends on the need to be able to access the hidden `i`.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The inner block will hide the outer.  However there *will* be a problem if the `INDEX` passed in is `i`.  This is why you frequently see weird variable names like `_i_` used in macros.  It's an attempt to avoid name clashes.

With modern compilers and hardware, there is little reason to fiddle with macros in his manner. Just use a function.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the `i` is only a problem, if you get `i` passed in to your macro as a parameter, because macros do pure text substitution.

Apart from that, there are several issues with your code:

1. The idiomatic way to wrap a void-function like macro is to use a `do { ... } while(0)` loop. Only that swallows semicolons correctly.
2. You have not wrapped all your parameters in parentheses as you should. If you pass `7 & foo` as `VALUE`, the expression `if(ARR[i] == VALUE){` will expand to `if(ARR[i] == 7 & foo){`, which won't do what you expect.
3. Your macro parameters are evaluated several times, so your code will explode if you pass something like `foo++` for any of them.
4. The element count calculation `sizeof(ARR)/sizeof(VALUE)` is plain wrong. There is no guarantee that the type of `VALUE` is the same as the element type of the array. If you calculate an array element count in a macro, always used `sizeof(ARR)/sizeof(*ARR)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK. The `i` in the macro will be only visible in the macro, and will also hide outer `i` within this macro scope.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be a problem, even you redefine `i` in `main`.

`#define FIND(VALUE,ARR,INDEX){\
    int i;\
    INDEX = -1;\
    for(i = 0;i <sizeof(ARR)/sizeof(VALUE); i++){\
        if(ARR[i] == VALUE){\
            INDEX = i;\
        }\
    }\
\
}`
Since you defined a own scope '{' within the macro.